# Clarification: Prove there exists a number $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $s_n >a$

Tags: proof-writing, alternative-proof

Below is the proof that I have been working on and the solution provided by the professor.

> Let $(s_n)$ be a convergent sequence, and suppose $\lim s_n > a$. Prove there exists a number $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $s_n >a$.
>
> > We will prove that $ \exists \ N$ such that $n > N \Rightarrow s_n >a$.
> >
> > Assume $s_n \rightarrow s+a$, since $s_n \rightarrow s$ and $s>a$.
> >
> > Choose $\epsilon = \frac{s-a}{2}$.
> >
> > Then $\exists \ N$ such that $n>N \Rightarrow |s_n - s|< \epsilon$.
> >     Thus, by choice of $\epsilon$, this gives us $s_n > a$.

I would like help understanding this proof. Specifically, I am not sure how we could choose $\epsilon = \frac{s-a}{2}$. I am also unclear about the last line, and why it serves as a completion to the proof (why is "by choice of $\epsilon$" sufficient?).

Comment: The sentence "Assume $s_n\to s+a$, since $s_n\to s$ and $s>a$" doesn't quite make sense.  You can't have $s_n\to s+a$ and $s_n\to s$ (unless $a$ happens to be 0)

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was odd too. I was thinking it should be $s_n \rightarrow s > a$ when I first worked through this proof.

Comment: Right, maybe that is what it was supposed to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose $\varepsilon$  as you please, *then* you determine an $N$ such that &c.

*Completion of the proof:*

$$\lvert s_n-s\rvert<\varepsilon\iff s-\varepsilon<s_n<s+\varepsilon.$$
In particuler, $\; s_n>s-\varepsilon=s-\dfrac{s-a}2=\dfrac{s+a}2>\dfrac{2a}2=a.$

Comment: That helps, thank you. Question: why is it acceptable to remove the abs value?

Comment: It iss the standard translation  of an inequality on absolute value into a pair of inequalities without it. It's quite natural if you interpret $\lvert s_n-s\rvert$ as the `distance` between $s_n$ and $s$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that for a chosen $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ s.t. for all $n\ge N$ the terms of the sequence $s_n$ belong to the interval $(s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon)$? Now to answer the question it suffices to choose $\epsilon$ such that $s-\epsilon>a$.  Draw a picture!

Comment: You know, I've never even thought to draw a picture with these... that's an excellent idea!! My text and prof certainly haven't shown us much...